# Do you think that moderators from MSDN forums should use our answers word for word?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

I'm participating in both Stack Overflow and MSDN forums. Today I read [the answer to the question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/02334418-446c-4274-85ba-935060e6daec) which interested me because I recently answered [the similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776635/ado-ef-code-first-generic-intermediate-class-inheritance-mapping). What was the surprise that a part of the answer looked quite familiar. Compare the last paragraph of MSDN answer with my answer on SO. What I'm surprised is that MSDN moderator even didn't try to rephrase sentences in my stupid English.

Before I started writing this question there was no link back to my answer on Stack Overflow. At least this has changed.

Comment: The rest of his answer is copy+pasted as well: from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399159.aspx)

Comment: I'm shocked, *shocked*, that a *Microsoft* -related site would act in any way unethically!

Comment: Well, these are the actions of one individual, not the company. But the guy definitely needs to be educated about copyright and how to quote properly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As far as I understand the terms of CC-Wiki under which your post was published, it is a clear violation of the license.

- You need to be explicitly pointed out as the author, including a link to your profile
- It needs to be explicitly pointed out that the text was copied from Stack Overflow

Just posting a link under the heading "similar threads" is *not* enough. This is simple plagiarism, and really stinks.

The rest of his answer is copied from [this MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399159.aspx)

Comment: Indeed; Jeff mentions [the same on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Answer (score 64):

This is nothing new.  I called MS for support once on some very obscure issue, and while they were researching they sent me an email with "some things to try."

While I was reading it, I was thinking, "damn, this is familiar."  The tech had copied one of my blog posts detailing my issue and what I had tried and sent it to me.

I lol'd.

Comment: +1, freaking hilarious

Comment: I wish I could favorite an answer.

Comment: haha, awesome. I'd love to see the day when I get sent my own answer to a problem.

Comment: Let me guess -- that was an "off-shore" support tech?

Comment: http://statestreetgang.net/post/2008/06/XAML-Serialization-FTW.aspx (edit at the bottom is in response)

Comment: @Gabe: Actually, no.  They eventually did help me, but their first response was to search for information online.  They just happened to find me first.

Comment: happened the very same grotesque thing to me with dreamhost support

Comment: @Won't. Had to do a bit of searching there, as your blog has had it's permalink structure changed (naughty, naughty!). [New location](http://statestreetgang.azurewebsites.net/2008/06/23/xaml-serialization-ftw/).

Comment: @TRiG: I know, tried to fix that, but failed horribly.  I could find only one WP plugin that did 301 redirects, but it doesn't appear to work correctly.  Not sure what I'll do about it, probably nothing at this point, seeing as how I've let the whole thing languish horribly.